# Is 'the local character set' the same as 'the encoding of the text data you want to process'?

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding

The Oracle Java Documentation states the following boast in its Tutorial introduction to character streams:

> A program that uses character streams in place of byte streams automatically adapts to the local character set and is ready for internationalization — all without extra effort by the programmer.
>   (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html)

My question is concerned with the meaning of the word 'automatically' in this context.  Elsewhere the documentation warns

> Data in text files is automatically converted to Unicode when its encoding matches the default file encoding of the Java Virtual Machine.... If the default file encoding differs from the encoding of the text data you want to process, then you must perform the conversion yourself. You might need to do this when processing text from another country or computing platform.
>   (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/convertintro.html)

Is 'the local character set' in the first quote analogous to 'the encoding of the text data you want to process' of the second quote?  And if so, is the second quote not exploding the boast of the first - that you don't need to do any conversion unless you need to do a conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of the first tutorial you have linked, I read it that they use "local character set" to mean the default character set.

For example:

```
inputStream = new FileReader("xanadu.txt");
```

They are creating a `FileReader`, which does not allow you to specify a `Charset`, so the JVM's default charset will be used:

- [FileReader(String)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/io/FileReader.java#57) calls
- [InputStreamReader(InputStream)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/io/InputStreamReader.java#71), which calls
- [StreamDecoder.forInputStreamReader(InputStream, Object, String)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/sun/nio/cs/StreamDecoder.java#59), with null as the last parameter
- So `Charset.defaultCharset()` is [used as the Charset](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/sun/nio/cs/StreamDecoder.java#66)

If you wanted to use an explicit charset, you would write:

```
inputStream = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("xanadu.txt"), charset);
```

Comment: I would disagree with your reading of the first tutorial as near the start it says  that the 'Character stream I/O automatically translates this internal format to and from the local character set', implying that the local character set is _external_ to the JVM.

Comment: The JVM's default charset (as returned by `Charset.defaultCharset()`) is determined by the `file.encoding` JVM property - there is nothing magical about it. This might be specified externally, e.g. it is picked up from your machine's environment when the JVM is started, but that's how your code gets it. `new FileReader("...")` definitely creates a `FileReader` which uses `Charset.defaultCharset()`.

Comment: [`FileReader(String)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/io/FileReader.java#57) calls [`InputStreamReader(InputStream)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/io/InputStreamReader.java#71), which invokes [`StreamDecoder.forInputStreamReader(InputStream, Object, String)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/sun/nio/cs/StreamDecoder.java#59), with `null` as the last parameter...

Comment: ... This means that `Charset.defaultCharset` is [used as the Charset](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/sun/nio/cs/StreamDecoder.java#66).

Comment: Thanks for all this.  It will take me a while to parse the information you have provided.  For the moment, can I take it that the answer to my actual question is 'no'?

Comment: For your updated title, correct, the answer is "no". The JVM will use its default charset, irrespective of the content of the file - it must do, because it chooses the charset before it reads anything from the file.

Comment: I have gone through everything and your attention to detail in the explanation has impressed me.  Some day I hope to be able to emulate the depth and care of thought which you display. Be happy. :)

Comment: Very kind of you to say.

Answer (score 1):

No. The local character set is the character set (table of character values and respective codes) that the file uses, but the default text encoding is how the JVM interprets the characters (converts them into their character codes). They are linked and very similar, but not exactly the same.

Also, it says that it "automatically" converts it because that is the function of the JVM: it automatically converts the characters in the text file that contains your code into code that the machine can read.

Comment: I get that.  I had a mistake in the original wording of the question which is fixed now, sorry.   I referred to the wrong bit of the second quote in my original phrasing.